# Implementing tests using context provider

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test if a function is being called when the form is submitted, but I can't do it.

```
// UsersContext.tsx
import { User } from "@/types/global";
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

// create context
export const UserContext = createContext<any>({});

export const UserProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  const addUser = ({ nome, email }: User) => {
    const newUser = { nome, email };
    setUsers([...users, newUser]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser({ nome, email });
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        nome,
        setNome,
        email,
        setEmail,
        users,
        addUser,
        handleSubmit,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My hook:

```
// useUsers.tsx
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "@/contexts/UsersContext";

const useUsers = () => useContext(UserContext);

export default useUsers;
```

My form:

```
// UseForm.tsx
import React from "react";
import useUsers from "@/hooks/useUsers";

const UserForm = () => {
  const { nome, setNome, email, setEmail, handleSubmit } = useUsers();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="containerForm">
        <div className="titleForm">
          <h1>Formulário</h1>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="boxField flex-col flex">
            <label htmlFor="nome">Nome</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={nome}
              id="nome"
              onChange={(e) => setNome(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="boxField flex-col flex">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              value={email}
              id="email"
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <button>Add User</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

My test:

```
// UseForm.spec.tsx
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import UserForm from "./UserForm";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { UserContext } from "@/contexts/UsersContext";

describe("Test UseForm", () => {

  test("it calls addUser when theform is submitted", () => {
    const mockAddUser = jest.fn();

    
    render(
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ mockAddUser }}>
        <UserForm />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

    // find two inputs
    const [nameInput, emailInput] = screen.getAllByRole("textbox");

    // simulate typing in a name
    user.click(nameInput);
    user.keyboard("felipesa");

    // simulate typing in a email
    user.click(emailInput);
    user.keyboard("felipesas@gmail.com");

    // find button

    const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button");

    // simulate clicking the button
    user.click(submitButton);

    expect(mockAddUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockAddUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      nome: "felipesa",
      email: "felipesas@gmail.com",
    });
  });
});
```

However Jest returns the following error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

How can I test if the addUser function is being called and if the state users has the registered information?

Comment: Your context contains only one property, which is not any of the ones the rest of the code is looking for.